# knockout js force rebind after sorting array items

Tags: arrays, sorting, knockout.js

Having trouble with knockout js. But seems to me it's a bug. Maybe there are some workaround.

There is an example of sorting list [here](http://jsbin.com/knockoutsortable/20/edit#javascript,html) and it works. And there is [another example](http://jsbin.com/erovah/3/edit) and it doesn't. The only difference between them is version of KO.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update:**
I don't know the reason but after calling splice method KO refreshes binding in some incorrect way. So the workaround I've found - force rebind array model.

The code I use to force rebinding is follows:

```
        // newArray is ko.observableArray([...])
        var original = newArray();
        newArray([]);
        newArray(original); // KO will rebind this array
```

Is there more elegant way to force rebinding?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are expecting, but I see _exactly_ the same behaviour in both pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe what is happening here is that Knockout 2.1 is correctly updating the list when you splice the new item into it, but the jQuery UI sortable implementation is **also** adding the item to the new list.

To get around this I added a 'dragged' class to the item that gets added by the sortable implementation, and then removed it once I updated the two arrays (which causes the UI update as expected).

```
    $list
      .data('ko-sort-array', array)
      .sortable(config)
      .bind('sortstart', function (event, ui) {                  
        ui.item.data('ko-sort-array', array);
        ui.item.data('ko-sort-index', ui.item.index());
        ui.item.addClass('dragged'); // <-- add class here
      })
      .bind('sortupdate', function (event, ui) {
        var $newList = ui.item.parent();
        if($newList[0] != $list[0]){ return; }

        var oldArray = ui.item.data('ko-sort-array');
        var oldIndex = ui.item.data('ko-sort-index');

        var newArray = $newList.data('ko-sort-array');
        var newIndex = ui.item.index();

        var item = oldArray.splice(oldIndex, 1)[0];
        newArray.splice(newIndex, 0, item);
        $list.find('.dragged').remove(); // <-- remove the item added by jQuery here
      });
```

You can see this working [here](http://jsbin.com/ujijeg)